# Choose searchable attributes on the front end

Tags: javascript, algolia

Is it possible to show the list of searchable attributes next to the search box? Or any other way the user could choose the attributes they would like to search by.

For example, to search for a movie, they could choose to search based on title only (not actor name or description etc.)

Ideally, this would be a `<select>` box before the search box.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with a custom widget

```
search.addWidget({
    init: function(options) {
        $('#select-searchable-attributes-input').change(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if ( value == 'all') {
                options.helper.setQueryParameter('restrictSearchableAttributes');
                options.helper.search();
            } else {
                var arr = [value];
                options.helper.setQueryParameter('restrictSearchableAttributes', arr);
                options.helper.search();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Feel free to ask details in the comments.